# Planning server infrastructure when hosting duplicated web-product over multiple servers

Tags: asp.net, architecture, production-environment, infrastructure

We have a web-application product that we sell to companies that is hosted at our servers.
The product contains couple of web applications, windows services and SQL server db.
Right now we have only one client that uses our product. We have two servers - one for the web apps and services and other for the db.

In order to add the product to another client, we have to 'duplicate' all the apps and db and run in separately.

As we started expanding and some companies will require more server power then others, I need to plan the servers infrastructure.

Having two servers for each client sounds ridiculous. Hosting costs will be huge. What will happen when I'll have 10 clients? And probably some servers will take more power than others, leaving servers using 30% from their capacity while others use 70%.

One thing I really care about is separating the DB from each product so in case of server compromise, only one db will be at risk.

So... I thought about Virtual Machines...
Does it sounds right?
Do I need two super servers to hold virtual machine instances? (one for web and other for db?)
What about Load balancing / etc..?
Will it require more maintenance time only because I use virtual machines?
Are there any hardware recommendations?

Any help will be appreciated

Many thanks

Comment: You might also want to look at Multi-Tenancy as a long term option; it would probably mean re-architecting your entire app, but definately worth knowing for future reference if you're not already familiar with it.

Comment: Some of the web apps can run on the same operating system but what with the DB? as I want to separate it from each client's server.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual Machines is definitely the safest way to separate clients and will allow you the flexibility to allocate a specific percentage of resources to specific clients.

However, using separate processes on the same physical machine will perform better (but not always significantly) and will allow more dynamic use of resources (i.e., if one spikes, it will use the resources it needs).  This setup will not allow you to control the resource allocation nearly as easily though.  You'll also have to build your own monitoring tools to see and analyze what processes (clients) are using what resources (piggyback on perfmon).

Using separate processes also is dangerous if your application wasn't designed for this.  Anywhere the application caches data on the file system or accesses anything besides memory and the database needs to be thoroughly scrubbed to make sure data from clients is not co-mingled or shared.

Separate virtual machines is more work to manage--each one is pretty much like it's own computer.  So you have to manage all the VM's plus the physical machine.

You may also want to consider hosting in a more dynamic environment like Amazon AWS or Microsoft's Azure which will allow you to more easily scale up/down as necessary than a VM at a traditional host.